# How to click on the first index in search drop down using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='uh-search-box']")).SendKeys("selenium");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        IList<IWebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_6_1472')]"));

         for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
        {
            IWebElement element = list[1];
            element.Click();
        }
```

}

Need to click on the first index (first suggested result in search field)
the code above does not work please help
http://screencast.com/t/gbWTiXzuDmC

Answer (score 0):

Try to use xPath like this `//*[@role='option']` and get first item in WebElements list